# How do I call a function inside the script from onclick in a button when using Astro?

Tags: typescript, button, onclick, astrojs

Here is my example. How to call greeting() function from the button?

```js
---
import Layout from "@layouts/Layout.astro";
const greeting = () => {
  console.log("Hello, server");
};
---

<Layout title="Hello, world" class="pt-10">
  <h1>I'm wondering</h1>
  <button onclick="">Click me</button>
</Layout>
```

Comment: It seems like you want a function to be ran on the server when a button is pressed. I fear that this is not possible in this way. For this to work, you would need to make a request to an [endpoint](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/endpoints/). You're also unable to define a function in the astro frontmatter and then reference it in the onclick event. For this to work, it should be below the frontmatter inside a script tag.  For further help, I would reccomend joinging [the Astro discord](https://astro.build/chat)

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe this is possible with Astro.

The frontmatter is always processed on the server, whether at build or render (SSG or SSR). [Frontmatter variables are serialized with `JSON.stringify()`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#definevars).

The button's onclick is processed on the client, and can only utilize functions already available on the client.

Astro docs recommend using `addEventListener` in a `<script>` tag for onclick functionality: https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#handle-onclick-and-other-events

```
---
import Layout from "@layouts/Layout.astro";
---
<Layout title="Hello, world" class="pt-10">
  <h1>I'm wondering</h1>
  <button id="tgt">Click me</button>
</Layout>
<script>
  const tgt = document.querySelector("#tgt");
  tgt.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Hello, on client");
  });
</script>
```

If you'd like a form on the client to run a function on the server: https://docs.astro.build/en/recipes/build-forms/